# How to set CSV Data row used only once in Jmeter with multiple threads

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have test with 40  Threads and all sharing CSV file with 5000 rows. I wan't all these threads use unique row during test no duplication. My Current flow is like this..

```
Test Plan
CSV Data Set Config (All theads)
OnlineQuote(Thread Group with 40 threads)
    Transaction Controller
       Submit Transaction (Get data from CSV)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are OK to stop test when data set if completely used, just set:

- Recycle on EOF = false
- Stop thread on EOF = false

Comment: I already have those setting but somehow i am getting duplicate requests. Seems like Multiple threads accessing same rows...

Comment: Check you don't have duplicates in your CSV file. Are you using distributed testing ? What sharing mode did you choose ?

Comment: so seems fine, then ensure you don't have duplicates in csv , I doubt there's a bug but if issue persists create a simple test plan with debug sampler and check and open a bug